# Coefficient of determination different in sklearn and GLM

Tags: regression, python, r-squared, ridge-regression, negative-r-squared

I have a linear regression problem and I am fitting a model in statsmodels and the same model in sklearn with Ridge Regression.
I get almost the same estimates for the coefficients, but the coefficient of determination seems odd to me. From statsmodels glm, I calculated it as 1-(model.deviance/model.null_deviance) and I get a value of 0.45. When I use the r2_score function from sklearn.metrics with y_test and y_pred as parameters, I get value of -2.244. As far as I know the coefficient of determination explains the percentage of variance explained by the model. How can I get such a number of less than -1.

Comment: Is your sklearn code testing out of sample?

Comment: @Dave yes, I am doing validation on a test set, if I understood the question well